# Adding multiple ranges for protection in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am wanting to add cell protection to various different ranges on the selected tab within my google sheet, I currently have the following script

```
function Protection2() {
  // Protect range
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range = ss.getRange('B16:BU16');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('This is now a protected range');
}
```

I would like to add further ranges to protect in this script I have about 50 ranges.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks